# Lisp function which adds parentheses in a certain way

Tags: function, recursion, lisp

I'm trying to write a function which adds parentheses like this: (parens '(a b c d e)) returns (a (b (c (d (e))))). I'm just not seeing the pattern very well. What I have so far just returns a list with parentheses around each element. I can't seem to figure out how to make it look like that.

```
(DEFUN PARENS (L)
   (COND ((NULL L) NIL)
   (T (CONS (LIST (CAR L)) (PARENS (CDR L))))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no parenthesis in a list.  You're starting with a list of five elements, `(a b c d e)`, and getting back a list of two elements, `(a (b (c (d (e)))))`.  The first element is `a`, and the second is another list, `(b (c (d (e))))`.

It's very easy to get *close* to this using `reduce`:

```
CL-USER> (reduce 'list '(a b c d e) :from-end t)
(A (B (C (D E))))
```

You can think of `reduce` as "injecting" the function `list` into `(a b c d e)` to produce

```
(list a (list b (list c (list d e))))
```

It's almost what you want.  You actually want:

```
(list a (list b (list c (list d (list e)))))
```

How would you produce that?  You can recurse down the list, and for each sublist `(x . ys)` you want to return `(list x (recurse ys))`, with the exception being when `ys` is `()`.  You don't want to recurse into `()`, because you don't want a list with two elements, you actually want nothing.  So the trick is stop recursing earlier than you typically do with a list.  Thus:

```
(defun parens (l)
  (cond
    ((endp l) '())
    ((endp (rest l)) l)
    ((list (first l) (parens (rest l))))))      ; *
```

```
CL-USER> (parens '(a b c d e))
(A (B (C (D (E)))))
CL-USER> (parens '(a b))
(A (B))
CL-USER> (parens '(a))
(A)
CL-USER> (parens '())
NIL
```

*<sup>*</sup>Omitting the `t` test in the last clause is intentional.  If there are no body forms in a `cond` clause, then the value of the test is returned.  Thus `(list …)` serves both as the test form and the value form.*

We can actually clean that up a little bit.  The case of `((endp l) '())` could be `((endp l) l)` since `l` is the empty list.  But that means that in both the first and second cases, we can return `l`.  We can call `(rest '())` in Common Lisp and get back `()`, so `(rest l)` will be `()` when `l` is something like `(e)` *and* when `l` is `()`.  This means that we can use:

```
(defun parens (l)
  (cond
    ((endp (rest l)) l)
    ((list (first l) (parens (rest l))))))
```

If we just have one test, though, we might as well just use `if`:

```
(defun parens (l)
  (if (endp (rest l))
      l
      (list (first l) (parens (rest l)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do it with `reduce` and some special consideration for the end:

```
(defun unflatten (list)
  (reduce #'list list
          :from-end t
          :end (1- (length list))
          :initial-value (last list)))
```

Note that `last` returns a list of the last *n* (default 1) elements.